# Unity 3D - Shaders with alpha break depth of field

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a scene where I really need depth of field.

Apparently, Unity's depth of field doesn't work with any of the shaders, neither built-in or custom, that process the alpha.

So this happens, for example, with the Transparent/Diffuse shader. Transparent/Cutout works instead.

Here's the simplest custom shader I made that triggers this behaviour:

```
Shader "Custom/SimpleAlpha" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGBA)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" }
        //Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 300

        ZWrite Off

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert alpha
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            half4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    } 
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

If you try the code in a project you'll notice that EVERY object that *wears* the shader is blurred with the very same amount instead of being blurred basing on Z.

[image: Depth of field problem. Cutout vs custom alpha shader.]

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

I posted the same question on Unity Answers: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/438556/my-shader-brakes-depth-of-field.html

Answer (score 1):

Since depth of field is a post processing effect that uses the values stored in the Z-buffer, the following line is the culprit:

```
ZWrite Off
```

For transparent objects, Z-buffer writes are usually disabled because the *Transparent* render queue doesn't need the Z-buffer.

So if you remove that line, you should see depth of field correctly applied to transparent objects. But objects lying behind fully transparent areas will now be blurred using the wrong Z value. As quick fix, you could try to use an alpha test like `AlphaTest Greater 0.1`.